# ctime lib, pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, ctime

```
tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
cout << "Year: "<< 1900 + ltm->tm_year << endl;
```

in ctime lib
why we must use `ltm->tm_year` but can't use `*1tm.tm_year`

Answer (score 1):

Because of the precedence of operators in c++

```
*1tm.tm_year
```

means

```
  *(1tm.tm_year)
```

you can do

```
   (*1tm).tm_year
```

but thats a bit ugly, hence this:

```
  1tm->tm_year
```